# Надпись на <button>

Tags: html, css

Не могу разместить надпись на изображение ( нужна надпись "Календарь" ). Через `value` не идет, т.к. не `input`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать?

Html:

```
<button type="submit" id="cal-btn">
   <img src="images/cl.png" alt="submit">
</button>
```

Css:

```
#cal-btn {
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:35%;
    width:20%;
    margin-left:42%;
    height:10%;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
}
#cal-btn>img {
    border-radius:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Почему вам через фотошоп не написать, прямо на картинке, или эта картинка используется для нескольких кнопок.

Comment: @Muson, это плохо по многим причинам. Самые очевидные: 1) Плохо выглядит при масштабировании, 2) Локализация 3) Не работают screen reader-ы (решается с помощью alt правда)

Answer (score 6):

Для ваших требований HTML примерно такой:

```
<button type="submit" id="cal-btn">
   <img src="images/cl.png" alt="submit">
   <span class="btn-title">Календарь</span>
</button>
```

А css получится таким:

```
#cal-btn {
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:35%;
    width:20%;
    margin-left:42%;
    height:10%;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    position:relative;
}
#cal-btn>img {
    border-radius:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.btn-title {
    position:absolute;
    line-height:0;
    font-size:14px;
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Это по вашей задумке.

P.S.: А вообще правильнее будет использвать картинку через background-image.

Html

```
<button type="submit" id="cal-btn">Календарь</button>
```

Css

```
#cal-btn {
    background-color:#dddddd;
    background-image:url("images/cl.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
}
```